# how to use INotifyPropertyChanged on treeview wpf

Tags: c#, properties, treeview, inotifypropertychanged

I dont know if the title question is right, but i'm writing a program that wheמ a client connects to my server i can reach all of his files using tree view and i do that by presssing on the listboxitem representig the client, and then i can view his files.
But when I press another client I see the the tree view of the first client that I pressed on the first time, I tried to use INotifyPropertyChanged but i didnt figured out how to use it.
I want to save the proprties of the tree view,
I also tried to do(trvStructure is the clients files tree view): `trvStructure=new TreeView()` and `trvStructure=null` every time i select new client from the list box but none of them works.
Is there another way to do it?
Also I thing it’s important to say that the tree view items are created manually by code

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just to do `trvStructure.Items.Clear()` every time a client is pressed